# Bug Initializing .bigqueryrc configuration file

Tags: oauth, google-bigquery

I'm starting to use Google's Big query tool via command line and I tried to run the command

```
>bq init
```

It gives this output

```
Welcome to BigQuery! This script will walk you through the
process of initializing your .bigqueryrc configuration file.

First, we need to set up your credentials if they do not
already exist.


******************************************************************
** No OAuth2 credentials found, beginning authorization process **
******************************************************************

Go to the following link in your browser:
```

Here appears a web url for google apis, the first time it gave me error: invalid_request. Second time I was able to link one of my google accounts and gave it permission. It gave me a code. When I wrote that code, it gave me this output:

```
You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Google engineers monitor and
answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag google-bigquery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well
as the following information:

========================================
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.7.6:Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
== bq version ==
  v2.0.17
== Command line ==
  ['D:\\Python27\\scripts\\bq-script.py', 'init']
== UTC timestamp ==
  2013-11-26 14:09:11
== Error trace ==
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 783, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 2082, in RunWithArgs
    client = Client.Get()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 604, in Get
    cls.client = Client.Create()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 584, in Create
    credentials = _GetCredentialsFromFlags()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 390, in _GetCredentialsFromFlags
    credentials = credentials_getter(storage)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bq.py", line 330, in _GetCredentialsFromOAuthF
low
    credentials = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, storage)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional
_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\old_run.py", line 156, in run
    storage.put(credential)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 325, in put
    self.locked_put(credentials)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\file.py", line 111, in locked_put

    self._create_file_if_needed()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\file.py", line 97, in _create_fil
e_if_needed
    open(self._filename, 'a+b').close()
========================================

Unexpected exception in init operation: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'%USERPROFILE%\\.bigquery.v2.token'
```

No clue what is it. Now If I try to run the init command again, it will give me again the same web url, but it gives me the Invalid_request error over and over again.

What can I do? The account(s) I want to link and give permission are linked to a project already who has Bigquery enabled already.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the report Mauricio. Can you provide some details about your Windows 7 installation that would help us reproduce and fix this problem? What are your HOME and USERPROFILE environment set to? Windows should set USERPROFILE automatically, but it appears that may not be the case for some reason. (I also see some Python bugs about dealing correctly with Windows where Unicode characters are included in the user's profile directory name-- that may be affecting you as well. If so, the first work around in my post below should work for you.)

Comment: HOME variable is set to %USERPROFILE%, but there is not an USERPROFILE environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are hitting a problem between Windows configuration and Python's implementation of "find the home directory" (more specifically, os.path.expanduser('~')).

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I filed a tracking bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=55&thanks=55&ts=1385494081 for this issue.

Here are a couple of work around ideas you can pursue:

First, you can specify exact paths to the files bq needs to use:

```
bq --bigqueryrc=<path to your settings file> --credential_file=<path to your credentials file>
```

After your bigqueryrc file is created, you can add this line to it:

```
credential_file=<path to your credentials file>
```

And then whenever bq starts using your bigqueryrc file, it will always apply the command line flags specified in your rc file and pick up the correct credentials file. Benefit: less to type in the long run.

Second, you can try to correct the problem between Python and Windows.

It looks like Python's [expanduser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d46c1973d3c4/Lib/ntpath.py#l275) implementation gives preference to the environment variable HOME and then the environment variable USERPROFILE. If these are not configured for some reason, you can set these to point to your user directory.